# How to run my Codeception test

Tags: codeception

The docs say to run `php codecept.phar run` to execute my test, but I believe this is an error.

When I run `php vendor/codeception/codeception/package/codecept.phar run acceptance` or 
`vendor/bin/codecept run acceptance EditUserCept` to run my `EditUserCept.php` test all I see is:

```
run [suite] [test]
```

Are the docs incorrect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The docs are correct. But I use the following:
**Examples**

- To execute *FooCest.php* found in the directory path *tests/unit/Model*
  `vendor/bin/codecept --steps --debug --verbose  run unit Model/FooCest.php`
- To execute all the tests labeled with the group **current**
  `vendor/bin/codecept --steps --debug --verbose  run -g current`

I would change to using *vendor/bin/codecept* instead of *vendor/codeception/codeception/package/codecept.phar* if you are running Linux or MacOS.